# how to get cpu usage percentage on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I've typed this command to get the history of cpu usage :

```
dstat -ta --top-cpu
```

and got data as the following :

[image]

my question is what type of data from the previous result should i take to compute the usage like the following :

[image]

Comment: You may find [this](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages) helpful... `top` can also be useful for 'load averages' - https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Introduction_To_System_Administration/s2-bandwidth-rhlspec-cpu.html - You can also make fairly good estimates using [System Monitor](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BUqIS.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the numbers that I circled. You get one value, for one second. Then, you do that for all other seconds, and get the average number, by adding all those numbers(for each second) and devide that number by the number of seconds. So, the sum of circled values is one value, which is used to calculate the average.

[image]

Comment: but am trying to compute the avg value ... but what numbers and data from the result should i take to make my table as in the second img ?

Comment: Ok, you didn't ask the question in the right way. I'll submit a new answer in a couple of minutes. Please wait.

Comment: Please mark as answered if this helped.